# Splitting books between 3 people such that two will have twice the number as the other

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There are 21 books and 3 people (a, b and c). How many ways can the books be distributed such that two people **together** will have twice as many books as the third?

My method is $\binom{3}{2}\binom{21}{14}$ which is simply choosing two people to have the "twice as many books" and the "twice as many books" is fulfilled by choosing 14 out of the 21 total

I am quite confident in the answer but this seems way too simple and I was provided quite a lot of space for working out for this question so it seems I may be missing something. If that is the case, please provide hints and blur the answer

Comment: don't you need to choose how you split the 14 book into the two people having twice as many book (and avoiding conting the situation again if you choose to give them 7-7) ?

Comment: Also it does not state whether all books need to be considered different for distribution or not.

Comment: The two people together have twice as many? Or each one has twice as many as th 3rd one?

Comment: This question is very poorly worded. It appears that your interpretation is that there exists a subset of the two people such that they receive $14$ books and the last person receives $7$. The question is not worded to make it apparent that is the intent. Another interpretation is that there are two people with an equal number of books, and that equals twice the number of books of the third person. This would imply that not all books are distributed. Another interpretation is that if the number of books distributed to each person are $a\le b\le c$, then you have $2a \le b$ and $2a \le c$.

Comment: Each interpretation could lead to a vastly different answer. Unless the question is made clear, any number of different answers are plausible.

Comment: Can you reproduce the *exact* wording of the question ?

Comment: Setting aside the poor wording of the problem, it is worth knowing that once the number of books $n\le 21$ actually distributed is fixed, there is a subproblem of what three integers add up to $n$, and that subproblem is often called the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$ (sometimes the *ordered partitions* of $n$).

Comment: @pFRAUX oh whoops I thought that was all accounted for in $\binom{21}{14}$

Comment: I am assuming the books are the same since the question just states "such that (numerically) two people together have twice as many books as the third" which implies they only care about the numerical value and thus ignore whether they are distinct or not?

Comment: All the books should be distributed @SlipEternal

Comment: @user71207 Thank you. That makes a lot more sense. Here is another way to look at the problem. You choose one person to receive 7 books. The other two people receive a total of 14 books. The possibilities are $(0,14),(1,13),(2,12),\ldots ,(13,1), (14,0)$ (I am writing these outcomes as pairs of numbers indicating the number going to person 1 and person 2). That is 15 possible numerical distributions of the 14 books. If the books are all indistinguishable, then you do not need to assign which of the 21 books go to which people. So, the result might be $\dbinom{3}{2}(15) - 2 = 43$.

Comment: But, that assumes the books are indistinguishable. (The $-2$ results from triple-counting the occurrence when the distribution is $(7,7,7)$)

Comment: But, if the books are distinguishable, then this problem is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @SlipEternal so what is wrong with my attempt? My result is $348840$ which is *a lot* higher than $43$

Comment: @SlipEternal On second thought, I think maybe the books ARE distinguishable, GIVEN that there was so much space to answer the question and thus more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the books are distinguishable and one person receives exactly seven books, then you still need to count the number of ways to distribute the 14 books among the two people. You had the correct start:

$$\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{21}{14}$$

This chooses two of the three people to receive 14 books (the last person receives seven by default). It then chooses 14 of the 21 distinguishable books (the last person receives the remaining seven books by default). Now, among the 14 books, you need to distribute them to the remaining people. How many ways are there to distribute 14 books to 2 people where every book gets distributed? You can look at it like the first book can go to the first person or the second person. The second book can go to the first person or the second person. Etc.

Finally, you need to subtract any overcounting. This counting method I described counts situations where you distribute seven books to all three people three times each.

> $$\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{21}{14}2^{14} - 2\dfrac{21!}{(7!)^3}$$

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. Glad I was on the right start for once!